# UWP C#: How to / Possible to: Refer to Page instance without creating a variable?

Tags: c#, uwp

2-3 weeks into the UWP part of the C# course now. And I am faced more and more with a dilemma that I am not a fan of. I've created 2 public static variables on the MainPage for holding instances of Pages so I can reach their respective public methods.

Essentially I have the MainPage variable as follows:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
    public static OtherPage otherPage = null;
}
```

Then, upon initializing the other Page, I do this:

```cs
public OtherPage() {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MainPage.otherPage = this;
}
```

And, I always do things not even mentioned in the course literature, just more fun to create my own projects and kind of push to boundaries for what I understand by experimenting with what I can come up with. But this often leads to the situations where I *know* there are better ways to do things. And this seems to me like one of this situations, really feels like there should be some way to access all loaded/active pages.

Best regards!

Comment: What's the relationship between `MainPage` and `OtherPage`? Why do they need to know about each other?

Comment: @mm8 Depends on the situation, different scenarios. But it revolves primarily around accessing public methods on the instanced object, i.e. not public static methods. It doesn't necessarily need to be from page to page, it could also be that I need to access the instanced page from my Core class to utilize public methods. Or even other classes rather than page classes as well. I.e. my class CreateCharacter.cs needs to communicate with the instanced Page of Scene_CreateCharacter.cs. But in essence: to access public properties.

Comment: The best practice is to use a view model class that you inject with dependencies. The page then binds to properties/methods of the view model.

Comment: @mm8 Do you have any documentation that I could use to investigate further? I've not delved to deep into dependencies so far.

Comment: Google or Bing for the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) design pattern.

Comment: For using Mvvm in uwp, please refer to [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm), and [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart) tell how to bind viewmodel property with your page.

Comment: You can always pass the instance of a class to the next page when you navigate to that page. Helpful if your new page requires some data from the first...